# CSS Sprite sheet animation with steps

Tags: css, css-animations

I am doing some mistake in animating the image.Can anyone help me in making it correct. [Codepen link](http://codepen.io/SantoshNeela/pen/QvEvPJ)

```
<div class="animation"></div>
```

Comment: codepen page not found

Comment: Sorry,here is the link http://codepen.io/SantoshNeela/pen/QvEvPJ

Comment: mmmh, this approach isn't correct..

Comment: You have to put a sprite with each step with the same width and height, like 10 steps, and in your keyframe animation could split the animation by 10 (10%,20%) and each keyframe move to this famous sprite width. Start by make a good sprite ;)

Comment: ok,thank you.I will do it with some proper sprite.

Comment: look at the answer, gl

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a sprite with each step with the same width and height, like 10 steps, and in your keyframe animation could split the animation by 10 (10%,20%) and each keyframe move to this famous sprite width. Start by make a good sprite ;)

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/

```
....

-webkit-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
   -moz-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
    -ms-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
     -o-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
        animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

....
```